# Python 3.5 for Windows missing tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have Python 3.5.1 for Windows (official python.org installer) installed and it seems to be missing tkinter. For example:

```
C:\Users\kostya>python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tkinter import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Does anyone have an idea about were I can download the package?

Comment: how did you install python?

Comment: from http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html "Tkinter (and, since Python 3.1, ttk) **are included with all standard Python distributions.** It is important that you use a version of Python supporting Tk 8.5 or greater, and ttk. **We recommend using the standard Python 3.x Windows installer which can be downloaded from python.org.**"

Comment: Exactly what I did. I grabbed the Python 3.5.1 installer off of python.org

Comment: you can find the folder where the standard library is located by importing another module and showing it's `__file__` for instance `import random ; print(random.__file__)` then go to that folder and look for a folder called `tkinter` to see if it is present.

Comment: The installer has an option "[X] install tkinter, IDLE, turtle".  It should be on by default, but you might have clicked it off.  If you run the installer again, you should see an option to repair.  That should get you an option to see if the box is checked.  Must sure it is and 'repair'.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks, that was it. If you add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installer has an option "[X] install tkinter, IDLE, turtle". It should be on by default, but you might have clicked it off. If you run the installer again, you should see an option to repair. That should get you an option to see if the box is checked. Must sure it is and 'repair'.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows, open settings and got to Apps and features:

[image]

Select `Modify`.

[image]

The click `Modify` (again) and then check the `[x] Tcl/Tk` box.

[image]